# Excel data validation as color value

Tags: excel, office365

I have very little knowledge of Excel, and am trying to make a data-validated chart.  For one column, I need the user to pick a color.  It can be any color, but is there a way for a color-picker to come up when one of those cells are selected?

Comment: What do you mean "pick a color", do you want them to choose from a list of colors, i.e. `"Red", "Blue", "Yellow", ...` or actually choose a visible color, without text? What have you tried? You'll likely want Data Validation of some sort.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific.  I know how to do a drop down list.  I was hoping for something like a color wheel, where they could pick a visual color, and it would put the hexadecimal value of the color as the value of the cell.